# Hilbert–Bernays provability conditions

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic, provability

Let "provability formula" ${\rm Prf}(x, y)$ written in the manner that provability operator $\square A$ defined as $\exists x\ {\rm Prf}(x, \overline A)$ satisfying Hilbert–Bernays axioms:

1. If ZF $\vdash A$ then ZF $\vdash \square A$.
2. ZF $\vdash \square A \to \square \square A$.
3. ZF $\vdash (\square A \land \square (A \to B) \to \square B)$.

From here I have to prove Goedel's Theorem, i.e. ZF $\vdash (\square \neg \square \perp \to \square \perp)$. Here $\perp$ is some contradiction, for example $(\Phi \land \neg \Phi)$.

Usually implications can be derived using deduction lemma. But here I'm little bit confused. Or maybe I understand "prove" incorrectly, i.e. it is not derivation?

Comment: Presumably, you need to start with a diagonal sentence. Perhaps: $A\leftrightarrow (\Box A \to \bot)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $T$ satisfies the Hilbert-Bernays conditions and that:

$T\vdash A \leftrightarrow (\Box A \to \bot)$

for some sentence $A$. Call this the *diagonal sentence*.

By the first and third conditions it follows that:

$T\vdash\Box A \to \Box(\Box A \to \bot)$

and thus by another application of the third condition:

$T\vdash\Box A \to (\Box\Box A \to \Box \bot)$

By the second condition we then get:

$T\vdash\Box A \to (\Box A \to \Box\bot)$

and thus:

$T\vdash\Box A \to \Box \bot$

Contraposition, the first and third condition then yield:

$T\vdash\Box\neg\Box\bot \to \Box\neg \Box A$

If we can show that $T\vdash\Box\neg\Box A \to \Box A$, then we'd be done. But the diagonal sentence can also be written:

$T\vdash A\leftrightarrow \neg\Box A$

Thus:

$T\vdash\neg \Box A \to A$

We can then apply the first and third conditions again to get $T\vdash\Box\neg\Box A \to \Box A$ as required.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me it is unclear how you applying first and then third conditions. As I understood, from $A \to B$ you can always derive $\square A \ \to \square B$. Can you show this please?

Comment: Sure. So  if $T\vdash A \to B$, then $T\vdash \Box(A \to B)$ by the first condition. Condition 3 can be re-written as $T\vdash \Box(A \to B) \to (\Box A \to \Box B)$. So it follows that $T\vdash \Box A \to \Box B$.

Comment: Why is there a *diagonal sentence* in ZF?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma

Comment: It seems too hard. This problem assume proof without diagonal lemma.

Comment: @Jihad Ok. Perhaps you could lay out what the assumptions are, since at the moment it's unclear what we're allowed to use.

Comment: I can use deduction lemma, modus ponens and Gödel's completeness theorem. In fact it seems that you proved more strict version of this theorem.

Comment: If those are your only resources plus conditions 1 to 3, then I don't think you'll be able to prove it. There are simple Kripke models (say with one world accessing itself) which model all of those assumptions and on which your required conclusion is false.

Comment: I'm sorry, in fact we can use this lemma =).

Comment: @Jihad No worries!